# Java Titled Border

Tags: java, swing

Is there any way to set font of the title of the titled border in java swing?

```
    JPanel panelDOB = new JPanel();
    panelDOB.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(171, 173, 179)), "DATE OF BIRTH", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, new Color(109, 109, 109)));
    panelDOB.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panelDOB.setFont(new Font("Tw Cen MT", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    sl_panelFac.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, panelDOB, 6, SpringLayout.SOUTH, txtNationality);
    sl_panelFac.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, panelDOB, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, panelFac);
    sl_panelFac.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, panelDOB, 61, SpringLayout.SOUTH, txtNationality);
    sl_panelFac.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, panelDOB, 196, SpringLayout.WEST, panelFac);
    panelFac.add(panelDOB);
    panelDOB.setLayout(new SpringLayout());
```

Comment: Besides the correct answer, the method would be `setTitleFont(Font f)`. - Just for information.

Comment: `Besides the correct answer,` which would be to read the API BEFORE asking a question. Reading the API is the only way you will ever know what properties can be changed.

Answer (score 5):

This is answered by simply looking up TitledBorder in the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/border/TitledBorder.html).

There you'll find two constructors (here's one),

```
public TitledBorder(Border border,
                String title,
                int titleJustification,
                int titlePosition,
                Font titleFont)
```

that take a font as well as a method for setting the font,

```
public void setTitleFont(Font titleFont)
```

Alternatively, there are two methods in the BorderFactory that creates a TitledBorder with your selected font, again available through the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createTitledBorder-javax.swing.border.Border-java.lang.String-int-int-java.awt.Font-).

```
public static TitledBorder createTitledBorder(Border border,
                                          String title,
                                          int titleJustification,
                                          int titlePosition,
                                          Font titleFont)
```

I'm frankly a little surprised that you didn't look into the API **before** coming here.